# Is if(document.getElementById('something')!=null) identical to if(document.getElementById('something'))?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When I want to check if an element exists in a page. Are these two checks the same? 
Is there a better more compact way to check the existence?

What if I want to check if the `value == ''`. Can this be included in this check as well?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A reference to an element will never look "falsy", so leaving off the explicit null check is safe.

Javascript will treat references to some values in a boolean context as `false`: undefined, null, numeric zero and `NaN`, and empty strings. But what `getElementById` returns will either be an element reference, or null. Thus if the element is in the DOM, the return value will be an object reference, and all object references are `true` in an `if ()` test. If the element is *not* in the DOM, the return value would be `null`, and `null` is always `false` in an `if ()` test.

It's harmless to include the comparison, but personally I prefer to keep out bits of code that don't do anything because I figure every time my finger hits the keyboard I might be introducing a bug :)

Note that those using jQuery should *not* do this:

```
if ($('#something')) { /* ... */ }
```

because the jQuery function will always return something "truthy" — even if no element is found, jQuery returns an object reference. Instead:

```
if ($('#something').length) { /* ... */ }
```

*edit* — as to checking the *value* of an element, no, you can't do that at the same time as you're checking for the existence of the element itself directly with DOM methods. Again, most frameworks make that relatively simple and clean, as others have noted in their answers.

Comment: There is also a lot of good info in this post.  (But I prefer to always check typeof by habit.)

Comment: Checking "typeof" in this case is completely useless because the return value from `getElementById` will always be type "object", even when it's null.

Comment: For me,  the whole point of jquery is that you would not need the "if". Just the jquery selector.

Comment: @batthink agreed - it's pretty rare that you need to check like that, but not outlandish.

Answer (score 23):

It's better (but wordier) to use:

```
var element = document.getElementById('something');
if (element != null && element.value == '') {
}
```

Please note, the first version of my answer was wrong:

```
var element = document.getElementById('something');
if (typeof element !== "undefined" && element.value == '') {
}
```

because `getElementById()` always return an object (null object if not found) and checking for`"undefined"` would never return a `false`, as `typeof null !== "undefined"` is still `true`.

Comment: There are many ways to check for definition.  And many ways to break them.  Say for instance you type (if (someValue) {}):  What if someValue == false?  It's defined, but it's false so the condition fails.  If you use (if (someValue != undefined) {}):  I can break your code by setting undefined = true.  typeof always returns a type string and if the object you are testing is not defined, it returns "undefined").

Comment: In this *specific* case, he's calling `getElementById()`.  We *know* what that will return. It cannot return the constant `false`, for example. It will return an element, or `null`.

Comment: Wow, setting undefined = true ... yikes.  I'd sure like to know what the rationale was for that being allowed.  Anyway, good explanation, thanks.

Comment: @Tim you can use `(void 0)` instead of `undefined` if you're paranoid.

Comment: what happened if i just do `if (element)`

Answer (score 6):

Just do it like this:

if(!document.getElementById("someId") { /*Some code. Note the NOT (!) in the expresion*/ };

If element with id "someId" does not exist expresion will return TRUE (NOT FALSE === TRUE) or !false === true;

try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
var createPerson = function (name) {
    var person;
    if (!document.getElementById(name)) {
        alert("Element does not exist. Let's create it.");
      person = document.createElement("div");
//add argument name as the ID of the element
      person.id = name;
//append element to the body of the document
      document.body.appendChild(person);
    } else {
        alert("Element exists. Lets get it by ID!");
      person = document.getElementById(name);
    }
    person.innerHTML = "HI THERE!";

};
//run the function.
createPerson("someid");
          </script>
       </body>
</html>
```

Try this in your browser and it should alert "Element does not exist. Let's create it."

Now add

```
<div id="someid"></div>
```

to the body of the page and try again. Voila! :)

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById('something') can be 'undefined'. Usually (thought not always) it's sufficient to do tests like `if (document.getElementById('something'))`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.  Try this.. lazy evaluation should prohibit the second part of the condition from evaluating when the first part is false/null:

```
var someval = document.getElementById('something')
if (someval && someval.value <> '') {
```

Comment: I would not recommend needlessly calling `getElementById` twice like that.

Comment: No need to evaluate `document.getElementById('something')` twice.

Comment: He specifically asked to check that the value of the element not equal '', at least that is how I read his intent..

Comment: Yeah, in which case you store a the element you get back from the getElementById() call and use that instead of calling getElementById() twice.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[jquery](http://jquery.com/) will provide you with this and more ...

```
if($("#something").val()){ //do stuff}
```

It took me a couple of days to pick it up, but it provides you with you with so much more functionality. An example below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* finds closest element with class divright/left and 
    makes all checkboxs inside that div class the same as selectAll...
    */
        $("#selectAll").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.divright').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: "Use JQuery" is worth an upvote all on its own?  Not even "If you're using JQuery, you could do it this way..."?  Man... Maybe I'd have more rep if I just posted "JQuery can do it" in every JavaScript thread.

Comment: lol. Good advice imho : use jquery for every javascript problem that is.

Comment: jQuery is "good advice" but it's not what was being asked.  I love what jQuery provides and use it extensively.  It's a great framework to get the hang of.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest version specially good if you just want to get the `.value` from the element.

```
document.getElementById('elementsid') ? function_if_exists(); function_if_doesnt_exists();
```